# How to successfully implement Salt_HAshed password Login

Tags: c#

I'm  having difficulties login in a page i've written using a salt-hashed password. Actually the code generates a 32-byte random salt taht it adds to the text inputed as password. then the hash of this is computed and stored in a table. However when one has to login, the text he inputs as password is salted with the same salt then hashed with the same hash function. if a match is detetcted then login is granted else, login is refused.   I have difficulties implementing that.

Help please . my code below

```
con.Open();
string salt = SaltF(32);
string Md = @"select Username, SH from SecureUser where Username= @usrn and SH= @sh";

SqlParameter usrname = new SqlParameter();
usrname.ParameterName = "@usrn";
usrname.Value = comboBox1.Text;
SqlParameter Sha = new SqlParameter();
Sha.ParameterName = "@sh";
Sha.Value = SaltHashF(salt, textBox2.Text);

SqlCommand cmdLd = new SqlCommand(Md, con);
cmdLd.Parameters.Add(usrname);
cmdLd.Parameters.Add(Sha);

SqlDataReader dr;
int K = 0;
dr = cmdLd.ExecuteReader();
while(dr.Read())
{
    K++;
}

if (K==1)
{
    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Login Successful", " ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    textBox2.Clear();
    ChangePasswordPlatform cpp = new ChangePasswordPlatform();
    cpp.Tag = this;
    cpp.Show(this);
    Hide();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password", " ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    textBox2.Clear();
}
```

Comment: So from what I can see, you are generating a random salt each time, and trying to find a match? How do you expect the random value to match the salt that was originally used in the database? You have to use the exact same salt value that was used when you first created the hashed password

Comment: To make your question valid we would need to see the code for `SaltF()` and `SaltHashF()` functions

Comment: I strongly recommend that you do not roll your own authentication framework. Use an existing framework to reduce security vulnerabilities. Take a look at [Security in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkytk30f(v=vs.110).aspx). TSQL also provides methods to encrypt and compare passwords. [PWDENCRYPT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd822791(v=sql.105).aspx), [PWDCOMPARE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd822792.aspx)

Comment: Please find the SaltF () And SaltHashF () functions below:

Comment: private static string SaltF(int size)
        {
            using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
                rng.GetBytes(bytes);
                return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            }
        }

        private static string SaltHashF(string salt, string pwd)
        {
            string PwdAndSalt = string.Concat(salt, pwd);
            string PwdSaltHash = Hash256F(PwdAndSalt);
            return PwdSaltHash;
        }